# Show % discount in configurable products magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, configurable-swatches

I have added the following code in /public_html/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml

```
   <?php if ( $block->hasSpecialPrice()): ?>
<span class="old-price sly-old-price">
    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($priceModel->getAmount(), [
        'display_label'     => __('Regular Price'),
        'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('old-price-' . $idSuffix),
        'price_type'        => 'oldPrice',
        'include_container' => true,
        'skip_adjustments'  => true
    ]); ?>
</span>
 <span class="saving-price"><span class="saving-text"></span>
  <?php
  $wasPrice = $priceModel->getValue();
 $nowPrice = $finalPriceModel->getValue();
  $saving = $wasPrice - $nowPrice; 
  $savingpct = number_format((float)(100*(($wasPrice - 
  $nowPrice)/$wasPrice)), 0);
   if ($nowPrice < $wasPrice){
   echo $savingpct. "% Off";
   }
  ?>
 </span>
 <?php  endif; ?>
```

Its showing % discount but on changing variation the % discount  is not changing its same as first product %

How to change the % discount on changing variations

Ex
if configurable options have 3 simple products A,B and C

If A has 10% discount,B has 20% discount and C has 30% discount

Its showing only 10% for all products on change

how to fix the issue

Comment: You need to use knockout JS for that.

Comment: directly editing Magento core file is not recommended

Comment: have you got the solution i'm also looking for the same..

Comment: Try my answer https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/7294079?key=df91ecfc0a50066db3978c4cab385b5e click here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/352928/82670

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This**

**Download Module:** [Click Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19eEw1jgX-_flQ_z3wiYL4UxgcO6hsmYY)

> **Install module into your Magento.**

**Output:** [Click Here](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/7294079?key=df91ecfc0a50066db3978c4cab385b5e)

***Note: You must have discount rule for the products.***